# How to check empty condition using PHP combinations?

Tags: php, combinations

Here I am having 5 fields:

1. clgID
2. empID
3. startDate
4. limit
5. papercode

Here all fields are mandatory, suppose any one of the field is empty means I have to return like `clgID should not be empty`  OR `empID should not be empty`, as per my knowledge I written the code I had posted [here](https://eval.in/1038232), but I think my logic is not correct. I hope we have to do `combination` logic but I don't know how to write this logic in PHP. Please any one update my code

My code:

```
//Test Case : 1 
$case1['testCase'] = 'Checking empty condition for all fields';
$case1['clgID'] = '';
$case1['empID'] = '';
$case1['startDate'] = '';
$case1['limit'] = '';
$case1['papercode'] = '';

foreach($mainArray as $key => $val){    
    $input['clgID'] = $val['clgID'];
    $input['empID'] = $val['empID'];
    $input['startDate'] = $val['startDate'];
    $input['limit'] = $val['limit'];
    $input['papercode'] = $val['papercode'];
    // $response = GetResponse($API_URL.'resultTrail', $input);

    if($val['clgID'] != '' && $val['empID'] != '' && $val['startDate'] != '' && $val['limit'] != '' && $val['papercode'] != '' )
    {
        $result[$key]['testCase'] = $val['testCase'];
        $result[$key]['resultCode'] = 'c001';
        $result[$key]['devTeamResult'] = 'success'; 
        $result[$key]['testingTeamResult'] ='test case success';
    }else
    {
        if($val['clgID'] == '' && $val['empID'] == '' && $val['startDate'] == '' && $val['limit'] == '' && $val['papercode'] == '' ){ // Checking empty condition for all fields
            $result[$key]['testCase'] = $val['testCase'];
            $result[$key]['resultCode'] ='458';
            $result[$key]['devTeamResult'] = 'Parameter not matching min requirement'; 
            $result[$key]['testingTeamResult'] ='test case failure';
            $result[$key]['data'] = 'All fields mandatory';
        }else{
            if($val['clgID'] == '' ){ // Checking empty condition for clgID
                $result[$key]['testCase'] = $val['testCase'];
                $result[$key]['resultCode'] ='458';
                $result[$key]['devTeamResult'] = 'Parameter not matching min requirement'; 
                $result[$key]['testingTeamResult'] ='test case success';
                $result[$key]['data'] ='clgID should not be empty';
            }else{
                if($val['empID'] == '' ){ // Checking empty condition for empID
                    $result[$key]['testCase'] = $val['testCase'];
                    $result[$key]['resultCode'] ='458';
                    $result[$key]['devTeamResult'] = 'Parameter not matching min requirement'; 
                    $result[$key]['testingTeamResult'] ='test case success';
                    $result[$key]['data'] = 'empID should not be empty';
                }else{
                    if($val['startDate'] == '' ){ // Checking empty condition for startDate
                        $result[$key]['testCase'] = $val['testCase'];
                        $result[$key]['resultCode'] ='458';
                        $result[$key]['devTeamResult'] = 'Parameter not matching min requirement';  
                        $result[$key]['testingTeamResult'] ='test case success';
                        $result[$key]['data'] =  'startDate should not be empty';
                    }
                } 
            }   
        }   
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to be writing out that much code? What happens if you have to add another mandatory field?

Instead, be more generic.

```
$requiredFields = ["groupID", "studentID", "startFrom", "limit", "worksheetID"];
foreach($requiredFields as $key) {
    if( empty($input[$key])) {
        return $key." is required"; // or whatever error message
    }
}
// if you get this far, ie. without hitting the "return", then all inputs are present.
// process the data now.
```

Comment: Well why the heck did you put `=> 10` in the array??? Use the `$input` array from your own code!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern for each input field:

```
$var = isset($_POST['field']) ? $_POST['field'] : '';

// Trim any trailing whitespaces
$conditionsOk = true;
if(trim($var) === '') 
{ 
    // Empty input
    $conditionsOk = false;
}

if($conditionsOk) { // Perform action: db update, email... }
```

Comment: No. I typed in my answer on StackOverflow, I will not meddle in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this opportunity to firstly, fix the issue to check if it's empty.

In php the [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function checks if the index is in the array, and if it's empty.

Secondly, let's go over the code and clean it up a bit; please review the changes; clean code is the most important factor in being a successful developer.

```
else {
  if (condition) { 
  }
}
```

Re-written to:

```
else if (condition) {
}
```

That's one of the issues with the code, the second issue is the cleanliness of the code; always try to keep the nested if statements to a minimum and move functionality to functions to keep the code readable and clean. - code that is not readable or maintainable doesn't carry any value.

I would go for a mapping and use a dynamic function.

Example mapping:

```
$fieldsMapping = [
  "field" => exampleValidationFunction(),
  "field2" => ["required" => True],
]
```

In return you can have flexibility and easily maintain the code albeit the learning curve.

The function to go over the mapping can be as follows:

```
function runTestCases() {
  foreach ($fieldsMapping as $field => $validationRules) {
    // your code here - check if its a function.. call function.. etc..
  }
}
```